# Emacs, C macro backslash stop

Tags: c, emacs, indentation

I am trying to figure out how to indent backslash in C define macro to certain columns.  The default value is to indent to 72 column max, but i need to indent to 76 and 80 column as well.

Which variable is that?

Comment: That's not indentation, it's line-wrapping.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel That's not indentation, he's trying to ask how to set the backslash in C code to specific column(like 72, 76 or 80) after hitting `TAB` when you trying to separate long macro definition into multiple lines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`c-backslash-column` and `c-backslash-max-column`.